# multiple calls to same service leading data loss

Tags: java, android, service, concurrency, broadcastreceiver

> I have a `service A`, which `inserts` MULTIPLE_RECORDS into `MULTIPLE_TABLES` , that `MULTIPLE_TABLES` i am using later in `another service B`. I have a `PHONE_STATE` receiver, which on `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` calls `service A`. EveryThing is working superb. Now begining of the problem :

---

Android 5.0 behaviour : `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` is triggering twice, `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` is triggering twice WITH NO WAITING CALL NUMBER, `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK` are getting triggered `TWICE-TWICE`.

---

And the problem starts, As i am starting `service A` from `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`, How i make service A capable of `DO NOT ALLOW OTHER INSTANCE TO RUN ME, IF I AM NOT FINISHED..` You can see i have tried it with `Boolean variable StateIdle`

---

Receiver :

```
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
        {
            StateIdle = true;
            IsNewOutGoingCall = true;
            OutGoingPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "NEW OUTGOING CALL : " + OutGoingPhoneNumber);
        }
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
        {
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                StateIdle = true;
                PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                if(InComingNumbersList.contains(PhoneNumber))
                {
                    Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "INCOMING NUMBER IS PRESENT IN LIST...");
                }
                else
                {
                    InComingNumbersList.add(PhoneNumber);
                    Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "Incoming number : " + PhoneNumber);
                    Intent InsertDb = new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class);
                    InsertDb.putExtra("TYPE", "INCOMING");
                    InsertDb.putExtra("PHONENUMBER", PhoneNumber);
                    startService(InsertDb);
                }
            }
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
            {
                //OutGoingPhoneNumber = "UNKNOWN";
                InComingNumbersList.clear();
                if(StateIdle)
                {
                    StateIdle = false;
                    Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "CALL ENDED... ");
                    Intent SendSMS = new Intent(context, SendSMS.class);
                    startService(SendSMS);
                }
            }
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
            {
                if(IsNewOutGoingCall)
                {
                    IsNewOutGoingCall = false;
                    Log.d("RECEIVER X: ", "ACTIVE OUTGOING CALL : ");
                    Intent InsertDb = new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class);
                    InsertDb.putExtra("TYPE", "OUTGOING");
                    InsertDb.putExtra("PHONENUMBER", OutGoingPhoneNumber);
                    startService(InsertDb);
                }

            }
        }
```

---

Thank you in advance, Hope someone helps me... :)

Comment: Should i use Smarter Runnable thread within OnStartCommand of Service A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well.., In short and sweet, If a `service` gets called multiple times, it starts `onstartcommand` multiple times... May be concurrent... `Causes data loss in tables and cases in our code that is dependent on table values` causes malfunction. As multiple concurrent threads executes same code in same time, a little ahead or back.., Use `IntentService` instead...

---

Main and `most Important difference` between a `Service` and `IntentService` is, Even if Intent Service is called 10 times...

1. It will start execution of first request..
2. If new call to that IntentService is made, then it will remain in waiting... As IntentService is being run...
3. When it completes first calls execution.., the second request in waiting will start executing IntentService.

---

Possible Simplest IntentService :

```
public class MyWorkerThread extends IntentService
{

    public MyWorkerThread()
    {
        super("SMSEngine");
        Log.d("MyWorkerThread : ", "\nCreated...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        // Your background code goes here..
    }
}
```